# Searching for the proof of a certain claim in Arnold's ODE book from 1992

Tags: reference-request, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, ds.dynamical-systems, citations

I was reading today the book of Stephen Wiggins called "Global Bifurcations and Chaos" (the 1988 edition).
On pages 12-13 he writes the following:

> Consider the following ordinary differential equation $$\dot{\theta}_1=\omega_1 \ \ \ \dot{\theta}_2=\omega_2 \ \ \ \ \theta_i\in (0,2\pi] \ \ \forall i\in\{ 1,2\}$$ where $\omega_1,\omega_2$ positive constants. Since $\theta_1,\theta_2$ are two angular variables the phase space of the above ode is $\mathbb{S}^1\times\mathbb{S}^1=\mathbb{T}^2$. If we draw the torus as the surface of donut in $\mathbb{R}^3$ the orbits of this ode spiral around the surface and close (i.e, they are periodic) when $\omega_1/\omega_2$ is a rational; alternatively they densely fill the surface when $\omega_1/\omega_2$ is irrational, see Arnold [1973] for a detailed proof of these statements.

The 1973 book is the ODE book; I cannot find a suitable copy, but I have the 1992 copy — does someone know where in this book the proof of these statements appears?
on which page?

Thanks!

Comment: And this is why all citations should include a page or theorem number.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See at p. 163 of this PDF link:

[https://eclass.uoa.gr/modules/document/file.php/PHYS289/Βιβλία/Arnold%2C%20V.I.%20-%20Ordinary%20differential%20equations_Red.pdf](https://eclass.uoa.gr/modules/document/file.php/PHYS289/%CE%92%CE%B9%CE%B2%CE%BB%CE%AF%CE%B1/Arnold%2C%20V.I.%20-%20Ordinary%20differential%20equations_Red.pdf)

Maybe you got confused because between the statement and the proof of the proposition you are interested in, there is a technical Lemma with its "proof". Moreover, this "proof" is willingly flawed (plain Arnold's style!), and just after the flaw is explained (but not corrected; that is left as a problem for the reader). Then the proof of the proposition you want starts (p.164).